# Using regexp with groups in Grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-templating

I have Grafana dashboards with “Stat” components and I try to change the display names.
I’ve found only one working way: add a field override using regexp. All works, but I can’t use groups in regexp. I want to do something like:

My_own_metric_(.+_.+)  ->  $1

I’ve tried a lot of different way to write it: $1, \1, ${“\1”},..
But I was only able to change it on static text.

I’m using Grafana-8.3.3-Ubuntu version.

Maybe someone knows a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's not possible to use groups in field override.
What you need to do is add an "operation" in the query itself:

`+ Operations > Functions > Label replace`

and set the legend:

`Options > Legend > Custom > {{yourlabel}}`.

So, an example for a straightforward mqtt exporter query,
changing the displayed label
from `$SYS/broker/clients/maximum`
to `maximum`:

[image]